How could I make this code apply to all the sheets?
The Macro below is what I use to change the properties of my pictures in one sheet but I would need to apply this to all my worksheets. What could I add here to make this happen?
Sub AutoMoveAndSizeWithCells()
    Dim xPic As Picture
    For Each xPic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
        'Modify the picture properties here
        xPic.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    Next
End Sub

Would really appreciate the helpl!

A same loop for the worksheets:
Sub AutoMoveAndSizeWithCells()
    Dim xPic As Picture, sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each xPic In sh.Pictures
        'Modify the picture properties here
        xPic.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    Next
    Next
End Sub


This will allow you to target a specific Worksheet or apply the code to all Worksheets.
Sub AllSheets_AutoMoveAndSizeWithCells()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        AutoMoveAndSizeWithCells ws
    Next
End Sub
    
Sub AutoMoveAndSizeWithCells(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim xPic As Picture
    For Each xPic In ws.Pictures
        'Modify the picture properties here
        xPic.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    Next
End Sub

